# OpenId to return always HMAC-SHA1

Tags: java, openid

I am using OpenId4Java-0.9.5, Is there a way i can always get HMAC-SHA1 algorithm, for OpenId. Although i am aware SHA256 is recommended.

Can anyone advise if there is any property which i can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override ConsumerManager associate method to do so.